# Can't generate user notification_key by sending web request from C#

Tags: c#, android, asp.net

I want to generate the user notification_key for the android application user. But as I run my code, i get an error : **"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."** at

> WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

Here is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net ;
using System.IO ;
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    protected void SubmitButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      AndroidPush();  // calling android push method
    }

    //Android push message to GCM server method
    private void AndroidPush()
    {

      var SENDER_ID = "76**********7";

      WebRequest tRequest;

      tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification");
      tRequest.Method = "post";
      tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
      tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("project_id: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

      tRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "key=AIz************************hpc");

      string json = "{\"operation\": \"create\" , \"notification_key_name\": \"gh******9p\", \"registration_ids\": [\"APA91b****************************************jJig\"]}";

      Byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

      tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

      Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();

      dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

      dataStream.Close();

      WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();
      dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();
      StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

      String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();   //Get response from GCM server.

      Label1.Text = sResponseFromServer;      //Assigning GCM response to Label text

      tReader.Close();

      dataStream.Close();
      tResponse.Close();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine. I even tested it it it works after I made a minor correction:
Please be aware that notification_key_name is just that, a name that you choose for naming your "group/channel", it seems like you are sending some kind of key.
Additionally, you might want to keep track on the service response, it will give you a key,that you will need to broadcast the notifications later. It will be very important for you to realize that once the group has been created, if you try to create it again with the same "notification_key_name", the service request will respond with a "400 Bad Request". Probable, that it's exactly what is happening to you now.